# How to reference an external binary by URI?

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I have a Thunderbird extension that mutates message bodies using an external executable.  Currently I do a hack-job and just place this executable in `/tmp/someBinary` and call it like so:

```
var exe = FileUtils.File("/tmp/someBinary");
var proc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
proc.init(exe);
var args = [msgBody.path];
proc.run(true, args, args.length);
```

This is obviously stupid, it would be nice to call it via URI and bundle the executable with the application.  Sadly, my limited JS means I only came up with the following:

```
var URL = ios.newURI("chrome://myExtension/content/someBinary",null,null);
var exe = URL.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL).file;
```

But that isn't quite right.  Is there a normal way to get this done?

Comment: Try something like this  var nsIFileS= Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL; and then use nsIFileS.init(...) to initialize it with the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to ask the chrome registry what the URL you have there resolves to:

```
var chromeRegistry = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/chrome/chrome-registry;1"]
                               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIChromeRegistry);
var URL = ios.newURI("chrome://myExtension/content/someBinary", null, null);
URL = chromeRegistry.convertChromeURL(URL);
var exe = null;
if (URL instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL)
  exe = URL.file;
```

Note that a `chrome://` URL won't necessarily resolve into a `file://` URL. Normally an extension is installed as a packed XPI file and the will only get a link to a file inside this archive, not something that the OS can execute. So you will need to specify the [`<em:unpack>` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests#unpack) in your `install.rdf` file.

This approach is simple but degrades startup performance (the extension manager doesn't unpack extensions by default for a reason). So a better solution might be copying your executable into the temp directory first time you need it.

Comment: That's perfect, you're great Wladimir.